# How to check if website is missing header that prevents content type sniffing

Tags: php, header, content-type

I want to know how can i check with domain name if website is missing content type sniffing header. Server is not mine, so I can not create php files inside or edit `.htaccess` file. i know that checking php version is possible with git bash and `curl` but is it possible to detect that missing header with `curl` too? or there is other way? (Only LEGAL of course)

Comment: use postman to send a request and see the response from such a request

Comment: Just check if the response has this header: `X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff`

Comment: it gave me `Content-Type →text/html` to content type but there is no `X-Content-Type-Options`

Comment: You could just open up the network tab in your browsers dev-tools, go to the URL you want to check,  look at the response headers in the network tab.

Comment: _"but there is no X-Content-Type-Options"_ - Then there's your answer. The site does not prevent content sniffing.

Comment: @madalinivascu Postman was useful and gave me exact results Thank You! If you write down that as an answer i will upvote it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you your answers was helpful. If you write down it I will upvote it (I mean answer about devtools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every major internet browser today (Chrome, Fx, MSIE...) lets you see in its developer tools the network transfers, including headers with each request and each response:

[image]

Comment: There were provided many useful answers but  you provided browser integrated answer and because of that it was most easy and fast

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -D option wit curl:

```
-D, --dump-header <filename> Write the received headers to <filename>



curl http://whatever.com -D myheaders.txt
```

Then open myheaders.com and look for the header you want.

Comment: myheaders.com or myheaders.txt