# Japanese characters are not rendered correctly on jsp page Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, utf-8, rendering

I'm trying to add Japanese charactes to a JSP file and render it and view using UTF-8.

jsp file :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Terms & Conditions</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="term-body">
    <h3>Account terms</h3>
  <div>
     <p>1. 同9後で票49女イ道済ゅれびス都関推ヘクセス読優ーた入北事フ注用テエヨモ図管ずばとッ医緒るょぽ訴番シケヲホ独横ム背本米とんば通一取ろみ掲相著よぼはレ</p>
     <p>2. 蔵身断ソムサ億領ワヱ報江ぐ万芸増ヨネ試梁レ芸同ヒ松成ウヲナカ換任ざどせ意足ヤヒコ護国げめそ援質か表過つぼ故企説階れクあぽ。</p>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml :

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But even the encoding is enforced i cant get this working. it ends up rendering like this

```
  Account terms
1. ?9???49???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

2. ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Comment: Make sure the JSP file actually saved in UTF-8 and not another encoding (i.e. UTF-16BE) while you're telling everyone otherwise. Open it in a hex editor.

Comment: can i do it on intellij IDEA?

Comment: By default the files are saved on UTF-8 on IDEA it seems

Comment: If "it seems" is enough for you then consider this problem solved. But I'd make sure. And also check the HTTP headers sent to my internet browser (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56790467/4299358).

Answer (score 0):

In my case for Japanese characters Shift-JIS encoding works on all browsers.
Please check by setting browser encoding.