# Setting html character set to utf-8 is not working

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

So I've been making a website and tested it on XAMPP. It showed the vowels and emojis I used on the website correctly.

But when I tried to put it on my web server I ordered at OVH they were formatting incorrectly, probably because the web server was configured with another character encoding.

So I've added `<meta charset="utf-8">` and even edited the .htaccess and added `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to it.

But I still have the same issue. There's no option in the WebHosting-Panel to change the character encoding. Is there any other option to show it correctly.
Thank you very much!

Comment: First check what the HTTP server is actually sending [to your internet browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56790467/4299358)

Comment: Check if the HTTP server is sending a `Content-Type: text/html` header either without a `charset` specified (in which case ISO-8859-1 will be the default), or with a `charset` other than `utf-8`. If either is true, that will cause a web browser to not interpret your HTML as UTF-8, despite your `<meta>`.